# Tkinter Frame Grids does not work and places them incorrectly

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Good day, I am currently restructuring my code in which I create several classes as frames and instantiate them at the end in the AllView. The problem is that several things are packed into the same frame and I don't understand that, since I have to create all the frames in the AllView.
For reasons of clarity, I have left out the code in some classes, because it does not play a role in the placement of the frame classes.
The button and plot frame will be instantiated later using a method
[image: Result]

```
   class GUI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        self.title("GUI") 
        self.mainTab = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.create_tabs()
        self.style = ThemedStyle()
        self.style.set_theme("breeze") #yaru #adapta #breeze

    def create_tabs(self):
        self.mainTab.grid(row=0, column=0)

        device = AllView(self.mainTab)
        self.mainTab.add(device, text="Device")

        # Random new Device
        random = ttk.Notebook(self.mainTab)
        self.mainTab.add(random, text="random")
        self.mainTab.grid(row=0, column=1)


    class MethodFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)
        pass

    class ParameterFrame(ttk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,master):
            super().__init__(master)
            pass 

    class PortFrame(ttk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,master):
            super().__init__(master)
            pass
    
    class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
        def __init__(self,master):
            super().__init__(master)
            pass
    
    
    class AllView(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
            self.methodframe = MethodFrame(self)
            self.portframe = PortFrame(self)
            self.paramframe = ParameterFrame(self)
            self.buttonframe = ttk.Frame(self)
            self.plotframe = PlotView(self,None)
            self.methodframe.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.W, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.portframe.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.S, padx=5, pady=5)
            self.paramframe.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.W + tk.E)
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are asking? You say "The problem is that several things are packed into the same frame and I don't understand that". I only see `grid` in your code I don't see `pack` anywhere? What was your expected result here?

Comment: I say my tab should be on grid 0, column 0
I say my method frame should be on grid 1, column 0
I say my portframe should be on grid 2, column 0
i say my portframe should be on grid 3, column 0

They are all supposed to be one below the other, but it doesn't work the way I thought it would

Comment: Please make sure you code is runnable. The posted code is incomplete and has broken indentation. See [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "grid 0", "grid 1", and "grid 3"? Did you mean to say "row 0", "row 1", and "row 3"? When I run your code, MethodFrame appears at the top of the Device tag, and PortFrame is below MethodFrame, and ParameterFrame is below PortFrame. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes I meant row = 0, column = 0 etc. But if I run the code as it is above, then my output is like the picture above

Comment: You have `sticky=tk.S` on `portframe` you maybe looking for `sticky=tk.W+tk.E` to *stretch* your frame in the cell.

Comment: I want each instance of a class to be graphed into individual frames in Allview among themselves. I don't understand why e.g. methodframe and portframe are placed in the same frame.

Comment: are you sure you have selected the desired frame as master for your label and optionmenu?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used classes when making my tkinter GUI but it looks like you may be wanting to use the toplevel() function to create new windows for yours, the below link offers a very good guide for getting started. When you make a toplevel frame, you will be able to grid/pack your elements into each newly created frame at the time it called.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-toplevel-widget/